# Is this the small (or large) inductive dimension?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis

I recently learned about the inductive dimension, but the formal definition is sometimes still a bit inaccessible. I have through experimentation however come upon my own definition for dimension which is easier for me to grasp, and I wonder if perhaps it aligns with either of the inductive dimensions:

> Definition: A chain of balls $\mathcal{C}$ rooted in a Topological space $(X,\tau_X)$ is a sequence $$\partial B_1 \supseteq \partial B_2 ...$$ where each $B_{i+1}$ is the closure of a non-empty open set in $\partial B_i$ with the subspace Topology, and $B_1$ is the closure of an open set in $X$. The *chain-dimension* of $X$ is the supremum of the length of all such chains, if it exists, and $\infty$ otherwise.

Clearly the chain dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ is $2$, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ has chain dimension $3$, so for Euclidean spaces, it seems to be $1+$ the normal dimension. My question is if the same is true for either of the inductive dimensions?

Comment: Why don't you begin with $B_0$ and the index of the last term of the sequence denotes the dimension of the space? On that case, for Euclidean spaces you'll get the same dimension as as the standard dimension.

Comment: @Emo I appreciate the comment, this is a good suggestion